# Сущеcтвует ли способ узнать, была ли модель провалидирована?

Tags: yii2, валидация

Существует ли функция/параметр в модели (которая наследует `yii\base\Model`), с помощью которых можно узнать, запускалась ли функция `$myModel->validate()`?

Конечно, можно реализовать такое самостоятельно, добавив в модель приватное свойство `$isValid`, после валидации присваивать ему `true` и получать кастомной функцией `isValid()`.

Но по-идее должен быть стандартный способ это узнать. В мануале, к сожалению, не нашёл.
Проверять с помощью методов `$myModel->hasErrors()` или `$myModel->getErrors()` не считаю хорошей идеей.

Спасибо.

Comment: чем hasErrors не угодил?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, hasErrors() вернёт false, даже если код $myModel->validate() не выполнялся (т.е. потенциальные невалидные входящие данные останутся без проверки).

Comment: Зачем нужно определять сам факт того, что **$myModel->validate()** выполнилась? Какую задачу вы этим хотите решить?

Comment: В проекте исторически сложилось, что валидация проходит в контроллере.
Поэтому хорошо бы добавить проверку и в саму модель чтобы исключить невалидные данные.
(альтернатива - переписывать код, переносить `$myModel->validate()` из контроллера в модель)

Answer (score 0):

Штатных способов это сделать в yii2 нет.

Решил добавить промежуточный класс между моими моделями и `yii\base\Model`. 
В новом классе добавил параметр `private $isValid = false;` который устанавливается в true в конце `afterValidate()`; функцию `isValid()` для получения статуса модели.

В таком виде всё работает отлично. Но это вынужденная мера, чтобы не лопатить кучу legacy-кода.